# Can となると・となれば be used with expressions of 意志・希望?

Tags: usage

[This site](https://edujapa.com/mikke/level/5/tonaruto/) has these example sentences for the となると・となれば grammar point:

> 結婚となると、住む場所は職場に近いところにするつもりだ。

> さすがに中学生となれば、親より友達を優先するようになりたい。

> ５年後に家を建てるとなれば、今から少しでも倹約して貯金しよう。

These sentences don't make much sense to me because となると・となれば seem to suggest a hypothetical situation and I am under the impression that 意志・希望 can't follow them. Am I right?

Comment: Though this is not probably relevant to the question, isn't the following 'hypothetical + wishing"? *If the weather is fine tomorrow, I'd like to go out*.

Comment: @sundowner In the case of that specific English sentence, yes, I think so. But as you say, it's immaterial in this case I think (reasons 1, Hypotheticals/conditionals are extremely language-specific, because it involves mood and syntax. 2. It's safe to say all Japanese teaching materials list this as a unique grammar point). I didn't really expand on this because I thought it was obvious (to native speakers and to learner's familiar with this N2 grammar point), but a lot of N2 sources in their explanations include a line that goes along the lines of 「後件に意志や希望を表す言葉は来ない」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that those sentences are slightly odd, but the following similar sentences are natural enough to me. (The translations are a little rough)

> 結婚となると、もう少し考えたい 
> (The partner is pleasant enough to be with, but) If the talk comes to marriage, I'd like to think it over a bit more.

> 英語学を専攻するとなれば、しっかりした発音を身につけておきたい
> If you major in English, you need to have a firm foundation in pronunciation.

> 20年後老後資金が2000万円必要となると、今から少しずつ貯めておきたい. 
> If one needs 20m yen for living after the retirement, which is 20 years from now, then I'd like to save little by little starting now.

Most probably, in Xとなると/なればY, wishes/intentions can come as Y, but those are wishes or intentions about what the subject does NOW (or before X happens). In all the sentences above, the latter part can be translated using *need to* (I need to think, you need to have, I need to save).

Strictly speaking, these are not really wishes or intentions but たい can be used anyway. (The particular usage of たい is similar to English *You may want to X* when suggesting to do X.)

---

For comparison,

- 来年円安が収まったら海外旅行に行きたい is normal
- 来年円安が収まるとなれば海外旅行に行きたい is (probably) odd

Following the above explanation, the first one is the most odd; The second is *If one comes of age of junior high, one needs to put preference to friends*; The third, *If I'm to build a house five years later, I need to save money from now*. The last two should be acceptable though I feel the second is a bit strange - possibly simply because of what it says.